# C++ compiler says "inconsistent deduction for auto return type"

Tags: c++, auto, reinterpret-cast, nullptr, stdoptional

There is this nice feature in C++ where you can say the function has return type "auto" and compiler will figure it out. However, what if I return a pointer and nullptr on error? Somehow compiler then fails to deduce the correct type and gives an error.

In the following simple example imagine `std::vector<int>` is scheduled to be replaced by something else completely in future, to justify the use of auto here:

```
#include<vector>
std::vector<int> e;
auto test(){
  if(!e.empty())
    return &e[0];
  return nullptr;
}
```

In c++17 I get above error message.

So I tried replacing last return by

`return reinterpret_cast<decltype(&e[0])>(nullptr)`

and get the error `invalid cast`. Only solution I see is replacing that return by the 3 lines:

```
auto out=&e[0];
out=nullptr;
return out;
```

I probably could reduce that to 2 lines by replacing `auto` with some kind of `decltype`, but I imagine some other kind of cast could do what I want in a single line?
Or do I need to use a newer version of the c++ standard for that case?

I also tried std::make_optional and get the same problem with nullopt_t being different type than std::optional.
What I really would love is if compiler would automatically deduce type to be `std::optional` anyway...

Comment: Hint: The type of `nullptr` is `nullptr_t`

Comment: `deduce type to be std::optional` ? If you want std::optional that's _completely_ different than a `int *`.

Comment: It has same interface. So with c++ starting to split between class and interface I can foresee the possibility for a hard push towards making nullptr and nullopt being interchangeable...

Comment: Another small warning, returning pointers (or iterators) into a vector is fragile. Since a vector can move its content in memory when it resizes. So replace it with something else sooner then later might be a good idea. What about returning std::optional<int> and just return a copy of the integer instead of a pointer?

Comment: The cast should be a `static_cast`, not a `reinterpret_cast`. `reinterpret_cast`s are useful only for a very small set of quite specific circumstances. Casting null pointer constants is not one of them.

Comment: I thought the other way around: static_cast is only for changing between child and parent class while reinterpret_cast is for everything dangerous. Don't know how pointers became childclass of nullptr_t, but I guess it makes sense...

Comment: @user45927 Yes, `reinterpret_cast` is always dangerous. If you intent to use it you should check what exact the cast will do.  Both `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` may be allowed, with only one of them having defined behavior. Casting a null pointer constant to a pointer type is not a dangerous cast. In fact it is an implicit conversion, so that no cast is needed (`decltype(&e[0]){nullptr}` is even weaker than `static_cast` and would also be fine). `static_cast` is for much more than parent/child casts as well. It should be your default approach if an implicit conversion doesn't do it.

Comment: @user45927 Pointers are not class types at all. There is no inheritance relationship between them and `std::nullptr_t`. That doesn't mean `static_cast` isn't useful though.

Comment: Also, pointers default-initialize to null pointer values, so just `decltype(&e[0]){}` or `decltype(&e[0])()` is also fine. (However `decltype(&e[0])(nullptr)`, while also working here, is unfortunately less safe, because is a much stronger cast than all the others. It is a functional-style explicit cast.)

Comment: In my previous comment I made a mistake: I meant "value-initialize", not "default-initialize". Pointers default-initialize to indeterminate values, not null pointer values. But the syntax I showed both result in value-initialization, not default-initialization, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

right, `nullptr` is type `std::nullptr_t` which is not type `int*`.

Static cast should be ok.

```
#include<vector>

std::vector<int> e;

auto test(){
  if(!e.empty())
    return &e[0];
  return static_cast<decltype(&e[0])>(nullptr);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sqfnqd69q

Even if `reinterpret_cast` worked (it doesn't), it would be overkill.

---

Regarding your follow up question, not sure what you want to achieve, but this seems close:

```
#include<vector>
#include<optional>

std::vector<int> e;

auto test(){
//  if(!e.empty())
//    return std::make_optional(e[0]);
//  return decltype(std::make_optional(e[0]))(std::nullopt);
    return e.empty()?std::nullopt:std::optional{e[0]};
}
```

---

I think this is more idiomatic:

```
#include<vector>

std::vector<int> e;

auto test(){
  if(!e.empty())
    return e.data();
  return static_cast<std::vector<int>::pointer>(nullptr);
}
```

I am a fan of `auto`, but this is one of the cases is better not to use it:

```
#include<vector>

std::vector<int> e;

auto test() -> std::vector<int>::pointer  // int*
{  
  if(!e.empty())
    return e.data();
  return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: _"more idiomatic"_ dear god both looks horrible. I'd argue the more idiomatic way is to return `int*` instead of `auto`.

Comment: @PasserBy, I agree. But that part was not part of the question.

Comment: Even though this does answer one of my questions, no upvote yet from me since the answer does focus too much on providing an explicit type or using obscure member-functions of std::vector. What I intended with my question is a situation where neither type of container nor its elements are known to the programmer at the time of writing the function. In my opinion that's what auto is really good for, write code before the technical details are established...

Comment: @user45927. there is no point on insisting with auto if you need to write decltype all over the place. And in this case you need to, because you need to convert the nullptr explicitly. Some would say that using operator& in the first place is obscure instead.

Comment: @user45927 there's nothing obscure about member typedefs, they've been there since the beginning for every class in the standard library. The point of `auto` is *not* magic, it's to allow you to write generic code, which will look even worse then this once you do everything fully generically.

Answer (score 5):

Just have one return.

```
auto test() {
  return e.empty() ? nullptr : &e[0];
}
```

> you should explain the issue with OPs code

There are two returns with different type. Which type to choose?

> and why this fixes it – 463035818_is_not_a_number

Because there are super long rules what type is the result of conditional operator. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator